# ¿Cómo exportar entornos virtuales de Python?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

Quiero exportar entornos virtuales de Python 3. Tengo varias carpetas (proyectos varios) que son entornos virtuales. Quiero llevar el conjunto de entornos a otro disco y que sigan funcionando como tales entornos virtuales. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

no tienes necesidad de exportarlos, es más creo que no hay tal forma, o no la conozco, lo que puedes hacer es:

- Comprimir tus entornos virtuales y pasarlos al disco que necesitas.
- Si no tienes virtualenv instalado, proceder a instalarlo, si no sabes como te dejo una forma de hacerlo.
- Primero identificamos la ruta donde tenemos python instalado y lo puedes hacer de esta forma, desde python pones:

---

```
import sys  
print(sys.path)
```

- Vamos a utilizarlo para mirar la ruta donde está instalado python.
- Accedes a la ruta y prosigues con lo siguiente:

---

- **pip install virtualenv**, así instalamos virtualenv en donde lo necesites, como ya debes de saber se hace desde la consola de comandos.
- **Virtualenv 'nombre carpeta'**, después de haber instalado virtualenv, procedemos a crear un entorno virtual
- si virtualenv 'nombre de carpeta' no te funciona, intentalo de esta manera.
  **Python3.6 -m venv 'nombre de carpeta'**.
- **cd 'carpeta'**, accedemos a la carpeta que acabas de crear.
- al acceder a la carpeta vas a ver diferentes archivos y carpetas, nos dirigimos a la carpeta scripts **cd Scripts**, y después ponemos **activate**, de esta manera activamos nuestro entorno virtual. Si no quieres acceder a la carpeta scripts lo puedes hacer así: **Scripts\activate**.
- Y ahora vamos a instalar django con el siguiente comando, con el entorno activado claro,  **Pip install django==1.10**, puedes cambiar 1.10 por la versión de django que necesitas para tu entorno virtual.

Así tendrás instalado virtualenv en el disco que necesitas y podrás pegar tus entornos, deberían funcionar correctamente.
Espero y sea de ayuda la respuesta.

Comment: Hola buen día, disculpen yo tengo una pregunta, le di formato a mi equipo y respalde la carpeta envs, ahora, como puedo utilizar esa carpeta de respaldo, que tengo que hacer para q de nuevo pueda trabajar en esos entornos virtuales que respalde??